# An infinite series of powers of fractions.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analytic-number-theory, zeta-functions

The series at hand is given by,

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{2k+1}{k (k+1)}\right)^s$$

I think it converges for $s>1$, but I have not been able to derive a general expression for this series.

I tried to evaluate it on mathematica and tried to find a pattern. This was an unsuccessful attempt. I also tried out a generating function approach, defining,
$$F_s (x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{2k+1}{k (k+1)}\right)^s x^k$$
I started out with the series,
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x^k$$
and found a series of appropriate steps involving taking derivatives and antiderivatives to obtain $F_1 (x)$, the idea being that the same steps must be applied recursively. In this way I wanted to find a pattern and attempt an inductive proof for $F_s (x)$ for any integer and I assumed that if I get it in terms of some 'nice' function (pardon the description, I am a physics student), the expression for any general $s$ would remain the same. But I hit a computational roadblock as I could not even find the expression for $s=2$.

I am looking for ideas on how to go about it.

Addendum: Would the closed form expression I find be the analytic continuation for the series for arbitrary $s$ in the vein of the Zeta function?

Comment: Try comparing it with the series $\sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{1}{k^s}$ to obtain its convergence when $s > 1.$

Comment: I think it does converge in this region. In fact I even checked the explicit sum for certain integer values of $s>1$ so that is not my main problem here. I just wanted to know how I should go about finding a closed form expression for the sum, which I expect to be dependent on the zeta function in some way.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe this series have a closed form?

Comment: That, I do not know. But I am interested in finding the analytic continuation of this series and I have found a formula for the same in a reference which I do not agree with for certain reasons pertaining to the way it seems to have been derived. I just hoped that someone with a stronger mathematics background could help me out with the derivation of the same.

Comment: As $s\to \infty$, a rough estimation of the sum is $\frac{6}{5}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^s s^{-1}$ if that is to any help. This is obtained from using the Euler-Maclaurin formula and only considering the integral. The above expression is the dominating term obtained from Laplace’s method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Partial solution*

I don't think that the general closed form of the sum exists, though we can find the closed form in the specific case of $s=2k,\, k=1, 2, ...\,$, and also get interesting asymptotics at $s\to0$ and $s\to\infty$

Denoting $\displaystyle S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{2k+1}{k (k+1)}\right)^n$, where $n=2, 4,...\,$,

we can write
$$S_n=\frac12\sum_{k\neq0,1;\,k=-\infty}^\infty\left(\frac{2k+1}{k (k+1)}\right)^n$$
In a standart way we consider the integral in the complex plane along a big circle of the radius $R\to\infty$
$$I_R=\oint_{C_R}\pi\cot(\pi z)\left(\frac{2z+1}{z (z+1)}\right)^ndz\to 0\,\,\text{at}\,\,R\to\infty$$
On the other hand
$$\lim_{R\to\infty}I_R=2\pi i\sum\underset{z=0;\pm1;\pm2...}{\operatorname{Res}}\,\pi\cot(\pi z)\left(\frac{2z+1}{z (z+1)}\right)^n$$
$$=2\pi i\left(S_n+\underset{z=0;\,-1}{\operatorname{Res}}\,\pi\cot(\pi z)\left(\frac{2z+1}{z (z+1)}\right)^n\right)=0$$
$$S_n=-\frac12\underset{z=0;\,-1}{\operatorname{Res}}\,\pi\cot(\pi z)\left(\frac{2z+1}{z (z+1)}\right)^n$$
As we have poles of order $n+1$ at $z=0;\,-1$
$$S_n=-\frac1{2(n!)}\left(\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\pi z\cot(\pi z)\left(\frac{2z+1}{z+1}\right)^n\,\bigg|_{z=0}+\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\pi (z+1)\cot(\pi z)\left(\frac{2z+1}{z}\right)^n\,\bigg|_{z=-1}\right)$$
$$=-\frac1{2(n!)}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\pi x\cot(\pi x)\left(\left(1+\frac x{1+x}\right)^n+\left(1-\frac x{1-x}\right)^n\right)\,\bigg|_{x=0}$$
Using the decomposition of [$\cot(\pi x)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions) near $x=0$ ($B_n$ denotes the Bernoulli' number)
$$\boxed{\,\,S_n=-\frac1{2(n!)}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\,\bigg|_{x=0}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k4^kB_{2k}}{(2k)!}(\pi x)^{2k}\left(\left(1+\frac x{1+x}\right)^n+\left(1-\frac x{1-x}\right)^n\right)\,\,}$$
This is the general answer for any even $n$.

Particularly, decomposing the expression near $x=0$

at $n=2$
$$S_2=-\frac1{2\cdot2!}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\,\bigg|_{x=0}\left(1-\frac{(\pi x)^2}3\right)\big(2-2x^2\big)=1+\frac{\pi^2}3$$

at $n=4$
$$S_4=-\frac1{2\cdot4!}\frac{d^4}{dx^4}\,\bigg|_{x=0}\left(1-\frac{(\pi x)^2}3-\frac{(\pi x)^4}{45}\right)\big(2+4x^2+6x^4\big)=\frac{\pi^4}{45}+\frac{2\pi^2}3-3$$
etc.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! So would you say that the extrapolation of this result to s=0 would be given by evaluating the expression inside the box at n=0?

Comment: To clarify, would it be prudent to assume that given the general sum say F(s) (for which we don't know the closed form expression), which is defined for Re(s)>1, can we say that the analytic continuation of F(s) would assume the same value at 0 as suggested by plugging in s=0 in this case. I know that the uniqueness of analytic continuation in general is only true for open sets but is there any other argument from complex analysis that we could appeal to?

Comment: I'm afraid we cannot use analytical continuation in this case, because $F(s)$ is not a single-valued function for non-integer $s$.

Comment: Right I understand. I think the contour probably needs to be modified to take care of the contributions from the branch points instead of the residue theorem treatment.

Comment: Interestingly, this process of extrapolation seems to agree with known analytically continued results at $s=0$ for the Zeta function and the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2k+1}\right)^s$ which makes me wonder if there's an argument that can be made without necessarily evaluating the sum for general $s$.